# Error Setting up Property During Unit Testing Using Moq

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq

Alright, let's assume I have a class like the following ...

```
public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public string Bar
    {
        get { ... }
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

... and as you can see it implements an interface so I can mock it. Now, in my unit test I'm building the mock like this ...

```
var mock = new Mock<IFoo>();
mock.SetupProperty(p => p.Bar).SetReturnsDefault("Some static value here.");
```

... however, when the test runs I get the following error ...

> System.ArgumentException: Property IFoo.Bar is read-only.
>   Parameter name: expression

So, three questions:

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. What do I need to do?
3. Can you please explain how I misunderstood `SetReturnsDefault`?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Obviously, the error message is telling you that you can't mock the read-only property like that. Instead, try:

```
mock.SetupGet(p => p.Bar).Returns("whatever");
```

If you want ALL string properties which are not explicitly set up to return some string then do this:

```
mock.SetReturnsDefault<string>("whatever"); 
// IMPORTANT: don't call mock.SetupGet(p => p.Bar) as it will override default setting
```

Answer (score -3):

try this:-

```
public class Foo : IFoo
{
    priave string bar;
    public string Bar
    {
        get { ... }
        set {bar=value;}
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

You must have to specify Set. Otherwise it will be read only.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem as `Bar` in the original interface is still read-only

Comment: additionally changing production code in order for tests to behave well, is not a good idea in maybe all cases